# Draw filled rectangle on image and control alpha channel

Tags: matlab, image-processing, octave

In Octave/Matlab how can I draw a filled rectangle (with 50% transparency) on an image?

I know how to draw an outlined rectangle like so:

```
img = imread('foo.jpg');
imshow(img);
hold;
rectangle('Position', [cx, cy, 10, 10], 'EdgeColor', [1,0,0], 'LineWidth', 50, 'LineStyle','-');
```

But the following will not draw a filled rectangle that is transparent:

```
img = imread('foo.jpg');
imshow(img);
hold;
%Draw filled red rectangle with 50% transparency.
rectangle('Position', [cx, cy, 10, 10], 'FaceColor', [1,0,0, 0.5], 'LineWidth', 50, 'LineStyle','-');
```

Comment: is there a reason you don't directly modify `img`?

Answer (score 0):

In MATLAB you can use `patch` instead of `rectangle`.

```
px = [0 1 1 0]*width + x;
py = [0 0 1 1]*height + y;
patch(px, py, 'Black', 'FaceColor', [1,0,0], 'LineWidth', 50, 'LineStyle', '-', 'FaceAlpha', 0.5);
```

Comment: thanks I will look into this function. Why do functions like `patch` and `fill` only take x,y arguments and not x,y,width,height arguments?? How the heck does it know the dimensions of the area I want to fill with just x and y?

Comment: I edited the question to make x,y,width,height more clear. The `patch` function can create more complex shapes than just rectangles. `px` and `py` define the coordinates of a path around the perimeter of the a shape which `patch` will fill in.

Comment: hmm its still drawing outlined rectangles not filled ones? Any ideas? https://imgur.com/a/zRgIp